# Error with unnest_token while cleaning up tweets data in RStudio

Tags: r, stringr

I have to tidy up some tweets I've mined so I can apply them to graphs and other analysis, but I'm having trouble with the tidyr and tidytext packages, it seems. I don't know if it's because I forgot to assign my file/data or if it's because of my column names.

This is my input:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

#load data

agriculturedata1 <- read_delim("agriculturedata1.csv", 
                               ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

agdt1 <- agriculturedata1

# regex for parsing tweets

replace_reg <- "https?://[^\\s]+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|\bRT\\b"

#split into words
words <- agdt1 %>%

mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, "")) %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "tweets")
```

My output should be a clean text without @, all letters lowercase and no URLs. But I'm getting this error message:

```
+   mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, "")) %>%
+   unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "tweets")
Erro: Problem with `mutate()` input `text`.
x argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
i Input `text` is `str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, "")`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
**<error/dplyr_error>**
Problem with `mutate()` input `text`.
x argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
i Input `text` is `str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, "")`.
**Backtrace:**
  8. dplyr::mutate(., text = str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, ""))
 10. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
**<error/dplyr_error>**
Problem with `mutate()` input `text`.
x argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
i Input `text` is `str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, "")`.

**Backtrace:**
     x
  1. \-`%>%`(...)
  2.   +-base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  3.   \-base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  4.     \-base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  5.       \-`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
  6.         \-magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
  7.           \-function_list[[i]](value)
  8.             +-dplyr::mutate(., text = str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, ""))
  9.             \-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 10.               \-dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
<parent: error/simpleError>
argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
>
```

A sample of my file:

```
   id     X1    tweet             date      
 1 1,27E~ 0     "The Santa Barba~ 12/06/2~
 2 1,27E~ 1     "The Santa Barba~ 12/06/2~
 3 1,27E~ 2     "@AnnBPissedOff ~ 12/06/2~
 4 1,27E~ 3     "\x93WaterFox\x9~ 12/06/2~
 5 1,27E~ 4     "Agriculture les~ 12/06/2~
 6 1,27E~ 5     "@HISTORY #MenTh~ 12/06/2~
 7 1,27E~ 6     "The Santa Barba~ 12/06/2~
 8 1,27E~ 7     "Curious about F~ 12/06/2~
 9 1,27E~ 8     "For farmers #Ag~ 12/06/2~
10 1,27E~ 9     "@ADITYA_101 @Ba~ 12/06/2~
```

I'm pretty new to R, so maybe this error is very simple to fix and I just can't see where exactly it's happening! If anyone have an easier way to clean minered tweets, it's also super welcome!

Comment: Please provide an example of your data set to make the error reproducible.

Comment: `> sample(agdt1)
A tibble: 10,068 x 4
X1        id           tweet                       date
1 1,27E~ 0     "The Santa Barba~ 12/06/2~
2 1,27E~ 1     "The Santa Barba~ 12/06/2~
3 1,27E~ 2     "@AnnBPissedOff ~ 12/06/2~
4 1,27E~ 3     "\x93WaterFox\x9~ 12/06/2~
5 1,27E~ 4     "Agriculture les~ 12/06/2~
# ... with 10,058 more rows`

Is this okay or do you need something else?

Comment: It needs to be minimal (no need for 10k+ lines) and in the original post rather than in a comment.

Comment: oh, ok! sorry! i'm really new to stackoverflow! i'll edit the post!

Comment: You don't have a variable called `text`?

Comment: @Phil no. should i change my column tweet to text?

Comment: In `mutate()` change any mention of `text` to `tweet`.

Comment: i tried it and now i'm getting this error `Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.`

Comment: What is the format of your tweet variable? I assumed it's string, but I guess not.

Comment: It is string. Some tutorials transform to corpus and I thought that maybe that could make this process easier?

Comment: What happens if you use `readr::read_csv()` to read in that CSV file?